# Can printf() produce "-.5" for the value (-0.5)?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, printf, string-formatting

i.e. can `printf` be told to ignore zero when it precedes the decimal point?

Comment: @halfdan are you aware of -any- in which it can? :)

Comment: @halfdan, I thought that most languages which implement printf simply pass it to libc..?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Python does exactly what @Amadan says... very useful for messing around quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all the things that are specified in ISO C99, this is not possible. The documentation for the conversion specifiers says:

> f,F: [...] If a decimal-point character appears, at least one digit appears before it. [...]
>
> e,E: [...] there is one digit (which is nonzero if the argument is nonzero) before the decimal-point character [...]
>
> g,G: [...] is converted to style `f` or `e` [...]

Since the other conversion specifiers would not print a decimal floating-point number, this is impossible at all. Unless you find a vendor extension that introduces another conversion specifier. But then your program would not be strictly valid C anymore.

The best workaround that comes to my mind is:

```
double number = 0.5;
char buf[80];
char *number = buf;
if (snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%f", number) <= 0)
  goto cannot_happen;

while (*number == '0')
  number++;
printf("%s\n", number);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure it can, but I'm afraid you won't be too happy with my answer:

```
printf("-.5", -0.5);
```

Comment: That will produce a warning, as there is no format spec in the "-.5" string :).  I appreciate a joke, but the answer should probably be a Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

In a word: No...

Comment: Yes `printf` can. See my answer.

Comment: @R..: No it cannot. See my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes. Use the `%g` format specifier instead of `%f`, i.e. `printf("%g", -0.5);`</strike>

If you're unhappy with the way `%g` prints some numbers in exponential notation, the alternative is to use `snprintf` to write to a temporary string buffer, and then count the number of zeros at the end before writing it outwith `printf("%.*s", num_nonzero_places, tmp);`, or you could just remove the zeros and use `fputs`.

Now I realize the question is about removing the leading zero, not trailing zeros. In this case, the best way I know is to use `snprintf` to write to a temporary string, then skip the first character when writing it out if that character is '0'. You'll need to replace the '-' sign too if the value is negative. One way to do this:

```
snprintf(tmp, sizeof tmp, "%+f", val);
printf("%.*s%s", tmp[0]=='-', tmp, tmp+1+(tmp[1]=='0'));
```

Comment: Wrong. `%g` is specified as either `%f` or `%e` depending on the value to be printed, and both of those are specified to have a digit in front of the decimal point. A quick test confirms this: `printf( "%g", -0.5 );` yields "-0.5" on my machine (Linux).

Comment: My bad. I was reading it as a request to remove the trailing zeros, not the leading zero.

Comment: all those strikeouts make my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your double or float to a char then:

```
while (*yourChar != '\0') {
    if (yourDoubleBeforeConversion > 1.0 && yourDoubleBeforeConversion < -1.0) {
        continue;
    }
    if(*yourChar == '.') {
        yourChar--;
        *yourChar = '';
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Explination:

1. while loop determines when the char ends.
2. If the double you had is greater than 1 then there is no point in trimming.
3. If it isn't keep checking for a ".".
4. When one is found go before and delete the zero.

Answer (score -3):

See the [printf spec](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/), and the precision section. You can do `printf("%+0.4f", -0.5);`

Comment: Well? Downvote mouse-over text reads: "This answer is not useful". This does apply since your answer does not solve the OP's question. (Not *my* downvote, but still - no reason to get personal.)

Comment: -1 for being a complete jerk in the comment; it's uncalled for an entirely inappropriate here.

Comment: Ok - Im going to delete my account.